# Admissible Bayes Rule

Tags: bayesian, admissibility

In the following wikipedia entry

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_decision_rule

it is written that

"Bayes rules with respect to proper priors are virtually always admissible"

What do they mean by "virtually always"? I know that it needs to be unique to guarantee admissibility. Is this why they say "virtually always" but not "always"?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some sections from my book, [The Bayesian Choice](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw):

> **Proposition 2.4.22** If a prior distribution density $\pi$ is strictly positive on $\Theta$, with finite Bayes risk and the risk
>   function, $R(\theta,\delta)$, is a continuous function of $\theta$ for
>   every $\delta$, the Bayes estimator $\delta^\pi$ is admissible.
>
> **Proposition 2.4.23** If the Bayes estimator associated with a prior $\pi$ is unique, it is admissible.
>
> Notice that Proposition 2.4.22 contains the assumption that
>   the Bayes risk is finite. Otherwise, every estimator is, in a way, a
>   Bayes estimator. On the other hand, some
>   admissibility results can also be established for improper priors. This is why we
>   prefer to call *generalized Bayes* estimators the estimators associated
>   with an infinite Bayes risk, rather those corresponding to an improper
>   prior. This choice implies that the Bayes estimators of different
>   quantities associated with the same prior distribution can be simultaneously
>   regular Bayes estimators and generalised Bayes estimators, depending on what they
>   estimate. This also guarantees that regular Bayes estimators will always
>   be admissible, as shown by the following result.
>
> **Proposition 2.4.25** If a Bayes estimator, $\delta^\pi$,
>   associated with a (proper or improper) prior $\pi$ and a strictly
>   convex loss function, is such that the Bayes
>   risk, $$ r(\pi)  =  \int_{\Theta}
>   R(\theta,\delta^\pi) \pi(\theta) \,d\theta, $$ is finite, $\delta^\pi$
>   is admissible.
>
> **Example 2.4.28** Consider $x\sim \mathcal{N}_p(\theta,I_p)$.
>   If the parameter of interest is $||\theta||^2$ and the prior distribution
>   is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^p$, since
>   $\mathbb{E}^\pi[||\theta||^2|x]  =  \mathbb{E}[||y||^2]$, with $y\sim \mathcal{N}_p(x,I_p)$, the Bayes estimator under quadratic loss is
>   $$
> \delta^\pi(x)  =  ||x||^2 +p.
> $$
>   This generalised Bayes estimator is not admissible because it is dominated by $\delta_0(x) = ||x||^2-p$. Since the classical
>   risk is $$R(\theta,\delta^{\pi}) = {\mathrm{var}}(\|x\|^2)+4p^2$$ the Bayes risk is infinite.

However, if one modifies the quadratic loss into a weighted version, as in$$L(\theta,\delta)=\dfrac{(\delta-||\theta||^2)}{2||\theta||^2+1}$$ the Bayes risk is finite and the resulting Bayes estimator is admissible.

Comment: If the loss function is bounded for an unbounded parameter space, it cannot be convex, which implies that some randomised Bayesian estimators can be admissible and other not. Again properness is irrelevant in that setting given that prior and loss function are only of interest as a product. It is thus always feasible to turn an improper prior into a proper prior by multiplication and change the loss function the reverse way.

Comment: Pure typo, as the interface does not handle LaTeX and quotes together.

Comment: What about non-negativity of loss? Isn’t that a requirement? Convex loss probably can be made non negative by shifting up but to be pedantic do we need nonnegativity?

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia entry needs to formalize such statement for sure so please take this answer with a grain of salt. I suspect it has to do with what you mention and the conditions under which Bayes procedures are admissible.

If there is only one Bayes estimator for a given prior, $\delta_{\pi}$, then it must be admissible. Furthermore, if $\delta_{\pi}$ is Bayes and

i) Unique, or

ii) support$(\pi)=\Theta$ and $\Theta$ is finite, or

iii) support$(\pi)=\Theta$ and $R(\theta,\delta)$ is continuous w.r.t.

then $\delta_{\pi}$ is admissible. Condition iii), in spite of being restrictive, is satisfied is most practical situations nonetheless, *e.g.* for exponential families, or when the loss function is bounded and continuous.

I hope this helps

Comment: This is a poor statement indeed as it does not mention the loss function, without which admissibility is not even defined.